# spacy model en_core_web_sm does not detect language entities

Tags: spacy

I wrote a small program to extract language entity from a text. I am using 'en_core_web_sm' but it does detect anything other than **DATE** from following sentence.

From spacy doc https://spacy.io/models/en, I can see that 'en_core_web_sm' support **LANGUAGE** entity.

I think thatI am doing some obvious mistake. Could someone please point out what am I doing wrong?

```
   nlp2 = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    test_text = "korean chinese  english spanish 2019-2-13 india america 2 years 6 months united states"
    doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
    for ent in doc2.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)
        print("\n")

Output
DATE 2 years 6 months
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of spaCy are you using? If I run this exact code snippet with the current latest version, 2.2.4, I get this print out:

> NORP korean
>
> NORP chinese
>
> LANGUAGE english
>
> GPE india
>
> GPE america
>
> DATE 2 years 6 months

As you can see, the pre-trained model `en_core_web_sm` does indeed recognise `LANGUAGE` entities.

As a quick tip: spaCy's NER module works better on actual sentences, which is what it was trained on. From my results, you see that it works also on non-grammatical sequences of words, like in your input, but it will make more mistakes because there is no grammatical context.

Comment: I was using version  2.2.3

Comment: Thanks for checking